# Material UI doesn't select a SelectField on hitting 'tab'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Using [Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) for some components in my app. 
I added a `<SelectField />` [select field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) in a form.

Is there a way to make it work like a normal HTML `<select>` element, so that:

- When you hit `tab` on the keyboard, it highlights it when it's supposed to
- When you hit `space` on the keyboard, it opens the dropdown

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm asking a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585727/how-does-one-programatically-open-a-material-ui-select-field without any luck.

Comment: i don't know what is your problem exactly but i think you can fix your problem with onKeyDown event in [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events)

Comment: Can you present a sandbox for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the link and TAB seems to work just fine. In any case: Consider upgrading to the current version (4.x). But I'm pretty sure 1.x and higher would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you click TAB few times? 
I used the page that you refer to and I see this after pressing TAB few times to make the drop down in focus:

[image]

after that hitting SPACE open the dropdown